# Getting all text nodes in xml using lxml xpath with original order

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

```html
<a>
aaaa
<b>
bbbb
</b>
cccc
<d>
dddd
<f>
ffff
</f>
gggg
</d>
eeee
</a>
```

how to use lxml and xpath to get a list. result must be [aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd,fff,gggg,eeee].
I can use the function xpath(u"/descendant::*[text()]") and 
xpath(u"/descendant::*[text()]") to get the result, but the order is incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> xml = "<a>aaaa<b>bbbb</b>cccc<d>dddd<f>ffff</f>gggg</d>eeee</a>"
>>> root = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml)
>>> root.xpath(".//text()")
['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd', 'ffff', 'gggg', 'eeee']
```